# Execute SBT task based on result of another

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

In my Play project I am trying to run my JavaScript tests before the standard Play's `test` task. I've written an SBT task and this works fine except I only want the Play `test` task to run when the JavaScript tests pass. At the moment the Play `test` task runs whatever happens with the JavaScript tests.

My `build.sbt` looks as follows:

```
val jsTest = taskKey[Int]("jsTest")

jsTest in Test := {
  "karma start karma.conf.js" !
}

test := {
  val exitCode = (jsTest in Test).value
  if(exitCode == 0) {
    (test in Test).value
  }
}
```

As I say `test.value` is always executed regardless of `exitCode`. How do I make `test` conditional on the result of `jsTest`?

Comment: Anytime you say `a := ... b.value ...`, then a depends on b, and b runs first before anything in the body of a runs. That's why what you tried didn't work. Maybe `taskDyn` would work? (see https://github.com/sbt/sbt/commit/d1ed57ef519b82ea32bbd1165bcc4e8f128c9e52) If not, maybe you need to write a command instead of a task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@SethTisue was right when he mentioned [dynamic task concept in SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks.html#dynamic-computations-with-def-taskdyn).

Add the following to `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val jsTest = taskKey[Int]("jsTest")

jsTest in Test := {
  "karma start karma.conf.js" !
}

test := Def.taskDyn {
  val exitCode = (jsTest in Test).value
  if(exitCode == 0)
    Def.task {
      (test in Test).value
    }
  else Def.task()
}.value
```

It seems to be working fine when `"karma start karma.conf.js" !` is replaced with `0` or non-`0` number.

Comment: How did this end up working for you? Although I can run karma just fine from the command line, sbt throws a java io exception claiming that it cant' find the file specified. Any ideas?

Comment: I've excluded `karma` from running when I tested the solution - I'd no idea how to have it installed/ready for testing. That's why I wrote *"is replaced with 0 or non-0 number."*